# How can you make Pdflatex to ignore empty \cite{ }

Tags: citing, cite-package

I have many empty `\cite{}` -commands in my craft like:

```
\cite{ }
\cite{ , , }
\cite{,}
```

This makes the compiler crazy.

**How can you make the compiler skips this checking?**

Comment: Why don't you use `\cite{X}` instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the following ignores all *empty* entries.

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\def\@citex[#1]#2{\leavevmode
  \let\@citea\@empty
  \@cite{\@for\@citeb:=#2\do
    {\@citea\def\@citea{,\penalty\@m\ }%
     \edef\@citeb{\expandafter\@firstofone\@citeb\@empty}%
     \expandafter\ifx\expandafter\relax\@citeb\relax\else%%   Test if empty
       \if@filesw\immediate\write\@auxout{\string\citation{\@citeb}}\fi
       \@ifundefined{b@\@citeb}{\hbox{\reset@font\bfseries ?}%
         \G@refundefinedtrue
         \@latex@warning
           {Citation `\@citeb' on page \thepage \space undefined}}%
         {\@cite@ofmt{\csname b@\@citeb\endcsname}}%
     \fi}}{#1}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
foo\cite{ }       % ignored
bar\cite{ , , }   % ignored
baz\cite{,}       % ignored
\cite{foo}
\end{document}
```